# DropZone.js not working using iOS

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

The file upload with DROPZONE.JS just working in Desktop Browser and Android Browsers. It actually isn't working when it's using iOS. It shows like the file it's uploaded but when I refresh the page it isn't there...

This is the code...

```
jQuery(function () {

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

Dropzone.options.imageUpload = {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    parallelUploads: 2, //limits number of files processed to reduce stress on server
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    accept: function(file, done) {
        // TODO: Image upload validation
        done();
    },
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
        // Pass token. You can use the same method to pass any other values as well such as a id to associate the image with for example.
        formData.append("_token", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')); // Laravel expect the token post value to be named _token by default
    },
    init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, response) {
            // On successful upload do whatever :-)
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
};

// Manually init dropzone on our element.
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#image-upload", {
    url: '/post-scheduling/add'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as @Chad, and the reason was the value for "acceptedFiles".
when I changed it from ".jpg,.png" to "image/jpeg,image/png" it started to work normally.

Comment: Verified solution. (thank you so much)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer will solve your entire issue, but it will at least be a solid start. I have just encountered a similar issue, so I've had to troubleshoot similar conditions.

In iOS 12, I've found the following to be true in both Chrome *and* Safari:

- I **am** able to upload photos of either orientation using the `Take Photo` option
- I **cannot** upload a photo that is in my photo library, though I am able to see and interact with all the photos contained in this section
- Using the `Browse` option, I do not have any images that I can test the upload with, but I *am* able to browse through the different apps' files

The first place I looked was the privacy permissions of Chrome. I had previously granted access to the camera, so that showed up (allowing me to upload photos via `Take Photo`), but the Photos privacy section did not contain Chrome (or Safari, for that matter). I believe this to be a bug, as in theory if Chrome does not have access to the Photos app, it should **not** be able to even browse your Photo Library. But currently, as stated above, you can in fact browse through it despite a lack of permissions in the privacy settings.

Next up, I had to verify that my server was configured to accept a larger max filesize for upload files (some phones nowadays including iPhones create some pretty large file sizes). This will be a different process depending on whether you're running apache, nginx, or another server configuration.

Lastly, make sure you have increased your `maxFilesize` inside your `Dropzone.options`. Right now, your code is set to 5 MB, and this is most assuredly too low for basically any smartphone since probably 2009 if not sooner.

Well, my issue is still unresolved after these steps, as I do not know how to fix what appears to be a bug in the permissions & handling of iOS's Photo Library upload. If anyone else can chime in, please do.